# How to get rid of this Seam

Tags: materials, uv, seams

I'm using a basic object from Zbrush to demonstrate my problem.

Using Zremesher to make a quite good topology import to Blender to unwrap it, then back to Zbrush to make a displacement. When I export my displacement map and plug it to Blender the seam is showing up, also exported texture map from Mari paint some tiling the seam is visible.

I've done a lot of tweaks in Blender also in Zbrush Displacement exporter, can't fix it

[image: I've done a lot of tweaks in Blender also in Zbrush Displacement exporter, can't fix it]

Comment: This doesn't seem like it's a question about using Blender.

Comment: This is probably a margin problem in the normal map, and as @MartynasŽiemys said, its probably the way you exported the displacement map in Zbrush.